# My csh shell alias is not working

Tags: csh

I am trying to write an alias for my svn source control which is under `/usr/xxx/bin/svn`.
Here the alias is not working after modifying the `.cshrc` file under my `/users/xxx` directory.

Here my `.cshrc` contents looks like below,

```
# Should all paths (even NFS, which might hang) be set up at login?
# The alias "fullpath" is available to setup your full path.  It can 
# also be used to change your path by changing USER_PATH above.
setenv FULLPATH true                            # 'true' or 'false'

###########################################################################
# Everything above this line helps configure the environment.

# This line should not be removed.
set dotdir=~/.files; if ( -f $dotdir/sys_cshrc ) source $dotdir/sys_cshrc
if ( $FULLENV != "true" && $?prompt == 0 ) exit

###########################################################################
# Everything below this line is run for interactive shells.
# If you wish the full environment even in non-interactive
# shells set FULLENV above to 'true'.

umask 022                                      # no write by group or other
unset autologout                               # disable autologout
set filec                                      # enable filename completion
set fignore=(.o)                               # don't complete .o files
set history=128                                # save last 128 commands
set ignoreeof                                  # disable ^D for logout
set noclobber                                  # disable redirect overwrite
set notify                                     # enable immediate job notify
set prompt="${HOST}:\!> "                      # shell prompt format
set cdpath = (.. ~)                            # where cd if dir unfound

if ( $?MAIL != 0 ) then
        set mail=( $MAIL )                     # mail spool
endif

##  
# Source other rc files after this line.
if ( -f ~/.cshrc_LOB  ) source ~/.cshrc_LOB
if ( -f ~/.cshrc_BU   ) source ~/.cshrc_BU
if ( -f ~/.cshrc_USER ) source ~/.cshrc_USER

source /auto/andatc/independent/shellrc-files/current/rc/.cshrc.build
set path = ( /usr/bin $path $HOME/usr/bin)
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /auto/nuo-common/swtools/svn/i386/linux/0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

setenv ANT_HOME /auto/nbv_proj/share/tools/apache-ant-1.7.1
setenv ANT_OPTS "-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
setenv JAVA_HOME /auto/nbv_proj/share/tools/jdk1.6.0_10
setenv SVN_EDITOR /usr/bin/vim

alias svn '/usr/cisco/bin/svn'
```

When I try to use svn in my workspace, I get the following output:

```
$ svn help
svn: Command not found.

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
```

Now to access svn, i am following the below steps.

```
1-login to the system and pwd shows o/p :/users/rakmohan
2-then cd /ws/rakmohan-sjc/
3-then /usr/cisco/bin/svn help
```

Comment: Does `/usr/cisco/bin/svn` in fact exist, and do you have permissions to run it? Rather than aliasing, why not just add `/usr/cisco/bin` to your `path`?

Comment: You probably aren't getting all the way through your .cshrc. Is your prompt as you expect it? Do you have SVN_EDITOR in your environment? You might put some prints in your .cshrc, then source it to see how far you get.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. You set `$FULLPATH` to `true`, but then you test whether `$FULLENV` is `true`.

Also, rather than setting an environment variable to the string `true` or `false`, it's more convenient to set or not set a shell variable:

```
set FULLPATH # or unset FULLPATH
...
if ( ! $?FULLPATH && ! $?prompt) exit
```

And as twalberg's comment suggests, rather than aliasing `svn` to `/usr/cisco/bin/svn`, it probably makes more sense to add `/usr/cisco/bin/svn` to your path. Or, if there are other commands in that directory that you don't want to make visible, you can create a symbolic link in another directory that's already in your path:

```
ln -s /usr/cisco/bin/svn $HOME/usr/bin/.
```

which you only have to do once; it doesn't require anything extra in your `.cshrc`.

Comment: currently to access svn, 1st i am login to the machine, then i ran pwd:

Comment: the above solution is not working.plz see my edited request and plz suggest.

Comment: @user2652753: I've read your update, but I don't understand it. What does "No wto access svn" mean? What happens when you type "/usr/cisco/bin/svn help"?

Comment: sorry, it was a small text mistake.

Comment: please have a look again.

Comment: @user2652753: As I asked before, what happens when you type `/usr/cisco/bin/svn help`?